# Patch Orchestration Application issue - NodeAgentSFUtility.exe crashing

Tags: azure-service-fabric

so I'm working on getting POA going. The issue I'm running into  is that as soon as the Node Agent NT Service (POSNodeSvc) starts, it runs NodeAgentSFUtility.exe which then fails with the below exception and an HRESULT of 80071c43 which seems to mean "connection denied". No logs are present. They both runs as SYSTEM . Running this on an on prem cluster using Windows security. BTW, all the SF services for POA are showing green in the SF Explorer, so it seems that there perhaps is room for better health reporting around this exe not running correctly.

```
Application: NodeAgentSFUtility.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient+IFabricQueryClient9.EndGetApplicationList2(IFabricAsyncOperationContext)
   at System.Fabric.FabricClient+QueryClient.GetApplicationListAsyncEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext, Boolean)

Exception Info: System.Fabric.FabricConnectionDeniedException
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.PatchOrchestration.NodeAgentSFUtility.Helpers.CoordinatorServiceHelper+<GetApplicationDeployedStatusAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.PatchOrchestration.NodeAgentSFUtility.CommandProcessor+<GetApplicationDeployedStatusAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.PatchOrchestration.NodeAgentSFUtility.CommandProcessor+<ProcessArguments>d__5.MoveNext()

Exception Info: System.AggregateException
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.PatchOrchestration.NodeAgentSFUtility.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

I was able to make this work by adding the following to the cluster manifest:

```
"ClientIdentities": [
                                       {
"Identity": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"IsAdmin": true
}
]
```

Not quite sure if this really is needed? Can someone please confirm. There is no mention of this in the POA docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-patch-orchestration-application

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: FYI I got an answer to this at the bottom of here - https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/353. There is likely a fix coming to POA where the exe at hand will be run with network service instead of system.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a POA fix coming to address this. See link in above comment.